# Select studios, films' amount, amount of honoraria' payment, honoraria' sum and average honoraria

Tags: mysql

I need to create selection that selects next:

1. Studio's title
2. The amount of honoraria that was paid by each studios for the last 10 years.
3. The average honorarium.
4. Amount of films which  was created by studios for the last 10 years.
5. Amount of honoraria which was paid for the films by the studios for the last 10 years.

I have three table: actors, studios and films. Actors and films have many-to-many, studios and film have many-to-many relationship. Actors and studios haven't relationship. Films_actors table also has field 'honorarium'.

So I can select studios, films and honoraria

```
SELECT studios.title, films.title, films_actors.honorarium
FROM studios 
JOIN studios_films ON studios.id = studios_films.studio_id 
JOIN films ON films.id = studios_films.film_id 
JOIN films_actors ON films.id = films_actors.film_id
```

The dump of MySQL database is next (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17ff2):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `surname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `studios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `founded` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `studios_films` (
 `studio_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `film_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `studio_id` (`studio_id`),
  KEY `film_id` (`film_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `films` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `director` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `budget` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `box_office` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `films_actors` (
  `film_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `actor_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `honorarium` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`film_id`,`actor_id`),
  KEY `actor_id` (`actor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `studios_films`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`studio_id`) REFERENCES `studios` (`id`),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`film_id`) REFERENCES `films` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `films_actors`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`film_id`) REFERENCES `films` (`id`),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`actor_id`) REFERENCES `actors` (`id`);
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: The SQL Fiddle is great. If you have sample data, you should add that in there too, and even the expected results from your data.

Comment: Also, are you looking for average honorarium for the last ten years, or forever? For all studios, or average by each studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to do verify without sample data, but I suggest you simply just take this step by step, which is how I will help answer your question. The first part is easy, I hope you can at least select a studio title.

For the second one, you can use the SUM() function on the honorarium column, and group by the studio id to get the total for each. You can use the WHERE clause to make sure the film date is within the last 10 years (which is the only date field I could find, so I assumed it was what you need.) That looks something like this:

```
SELECT s.title, SUM(fa.honorarium) AS totalHonorarium
FROM studios s
JOIN studios_films sf ON sf.studio_id = s.id
JOIN films f ON f.id = sf.film_id
JOIN films_actors fa ON fa.film_id = f.id
WHERE f.created >= (SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 YEAR))
GROUP BY s.id;
```

For the next part, there is some ambiguity in your question to me. Do you want the average amount of honorarium from all studios, or the average for each individual studio? You also didn't specify 'for the last ten years' which is what everything else is using. I will edit this answer after I hear back from you.

To get the amount of films created by the studio for the last 10 years, you can just adjust the above query to include a COUNT() function. Here, you want to count the distinct film_ids for each studio_id. So try this:

```
SELECT s.title, SUM(fa.honorarium) AS totalHonorarium, COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) AS totalFilms
FROM studios s
JOIN studios_films sf ON sf.studio_id = s.id
JOIN films f ON f.id = sf.film_id
JOIN films_actors fa ON fa.film_id = f.id
WHERE f.created >= (SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 YEAR))
GROUP BY s.id;
```

Last, to get the honorarium for each film by each studio (which is how I understand your question) you'll need another query, since your grouping is going to change. It should look something like this:

```
SELECT s.title, f.id, SUM(fa.honorarium) AS totalHonorariumForFilm
FROM studios s
JOIN studios_films sf ON sf.studio_id = s.id
JOIN films f ON f.id = sf.film_id
JOIN films_actors fa ON fa.film_id = f.id
WHERE f.created >= (SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 YEAR))
GROUP BY s.id, f.id;
```

And here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d7b8d/2) for those examples, with some dummy data that I put in myself. Let me know if you have any questions, if you still have trouble with average honorarium explain to me your needs and I can help you work it out.

**EDIT**

You can also work foreign keys into your create table statement, rather than alter the table. This helps avoid some insertion issues. I've made a few suggested edits [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18a34).

**EDIT 2**

Regarding you edit, you can use the same joins as the first query, and implement some various aggregate functions to get the values you need. Since you're still getting these values per studio, the grouping remains the same. Try this out:

```
SELECT s.title, COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) AS totalFilms, COUNT(fa.film_id) AS amountOfHonorarium, SUM(fa.honorarium) AS totalHonorarium, AVG(fa.honorarium) AS averageHonorarium
FROM studios s
JOIN studios_films sf ON sf.studio_id = s.id
JOIN films f ON f.id = sf.film_id
JOIN films_actors fa ON fa.film_id = f.id
WHERE f.created >= (SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 YEAR))
GROUP BY s.id;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd8f5c/4) with that in it. As far as the honorarium per film, I think you can just pull film title and the sum of honorarium and group by film, like this:

```
SELECT f.title, SUM(fa.honorarium) AS honorariumForFilm
FROM films f
JOIN films_actors fa ON fa.film_id = f.id
GROUP BY f.id;
```

Let me know if that produces better results. If confusion remains, I will continue to help.

Comment: Thanks for so deep answer. And sorry for my bad explanation. I'll add some information under this comment

Comment: @Antin were you going to add more to that?

Comment: @Antin I just saw your edit. I will play with this some more and see what I can do.

Comment: I tried to create query after I read your first answer. And it works! Then I read you second answer and my query almost identical to yours! It's great! It's very important to me to understand not only copy-past! Thanks for help! Only problem is division paying of honorarium between companies which produced film.      For examle. 'Sin City 2' was created by Dimension, Troublemaker and Miramax. Total honorarium of all actors (E.Green, B.Willis, J.Gordon-Levitt, M.Rourke) amounted 4572578.

Comment: And total honorarium was paid by these 3 studios. But query gives info that EACH studio has paid 4572578! It's mistake((( I know that without info about honorarium's share that each studio to pay I can create such query. So how can I united studios which produce film and pay honorarium?

Comment: @Antin try changing the `SUM(fa.honorarium)` to average and let me know if that produces your expected results. If It does I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for help! All work good! I don/t need create query for films which have more than one studios. Without info about studios which pay s honorarium we can't create right query